# Split entrySet and filter in java 8 using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an issue with streams

I have a `Map<LocalDateTime, Set<Vote>> map = new HashMap<>();`

I have to count the number of votes and put it in a new map grouped by localDateTime but I need to count only the vote filtered by Type. I don't know how to do this with a stream.

I have tried this but it doesn't work and it doens't even compile

```
public Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> numbersOfVotes(TypeVote typeVote) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().filter(en -> en.getValue().stream().filter(v -> v.getTypeVote().equals(typeVote)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().size()));
}
```

Class vote has 2 attributes, name and TypeVote (enum)

```
public Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> numbersOfVotes(TypeVote typeVote) {
    return null;
}
```

My return value must be `Map<LocalDateTime, Integer>`.

How to do this using streams in Java 8 ?

Comment: How to do the filtering?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: public Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> numbersOfVotes(TypeVote typeVote) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().filter(en -> en.getValue().stream().filter(v -> v.getTypeVote().equals(typeVote)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().size()));
}

Answer (score 1):

```
final Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                (Map.Entry<LocalDateTime, Set<Vote>> entry) -> (int) entry.getValue().stream()
                        .filter((Vote vote) -> true) // Here insert real filtering
                        .count()));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferable to avoid the type of the second parameter of Collectors.toMap() to improve readability?

Comment: Depends - with IntelliJ I mostly avoid it but with NetBeans and Eclipse I mostly add it because some older versions of their IDEs couldn't display the type as good as IntelliJ did.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
Function<Map.Entry<LocalDateTime, Set<Vote>>, Integer> fun =  e -> (int) e.getValue()
            .stream().filter(vote -> typeVote.equals(vote.getTypeVote()))
            .count();

Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> collect = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, fun));
```